# Select from table A which does not exist in table B with condition in table B

Tags: mysql

I have tableA

```
id  | name      
--------------
1   | John
2   | Alice     
3   | Bob
```

and table B

```
id  | tableA_id | setting 
--------------------------
1   | 1         |  1
2   | 2         |  0
```

I want to select all unique ids in table A which do not exist in table B with a condition in table B setting = 0.

Example I would like receive

```
id  | name      
--------------
1   | John    
3   | Bob
```

I can use query:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT tableA_id from tableB WHERE setting = 0)
```

But I think it is slowly because 2 tables is large. I think this query affect to performance.

how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;)

```
select t1.*
from tableA t1
left join tableB t2
on t1.id = t2.tableA_id
where t2.setting <> 0 or t2.id is null
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa8af/15)

Or this:

```
select *
from tableA
where not exists (
    select 1 from tableB where tableA.id = tableB.tableA_id and tableB.setting = 0
)
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa8af/12)

Comment: yea, anything but `not in`

Comment: it not working. With case 1: result only has 1 record "1   | John"
In case 2: result has everything in table a

Comment: @Khaihkd case 1 is definitely wrong and I've updated, please check the demo; case 2 seems to be right, also check demo please.:D

Comment: ok thanks. It work. do you think performance of queries is better than `not in`

Comment: About this, you can `explain` this query and your query in your db, check the explain result please.